# Add a datalist option to inform of "no result"

Tags: javascript, html, input

I'm trying to add a datalist item to inform the user that their input has no corresponding result. However, the option is not showing.

I have the following html:

```
<div id="searchBoxDiv" class="level-item">
  <input id="searchBox" class="input" type="text" list="searchBoxResults" placeholder="Rechercher un bateau">

  <!-- Add a list below for suggestions -->

  <datalist id="searchBoxResults">

  </datalist>
</div>
```

And the following js:

```
searchBox.addEventListener("input", function () {
  //Get the value of the searchBox
  let searchValue = searchBox.value;
  
  let features = ["a", "aa", "b"];

  //Get the features that match the search value
  let matchingFeatures = features.filter(function (feature) {  
    return feature.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue.toLowerCase());
  });

  //If the content of the searchBox, that's the one
  if (matchingFeatures.length === 1 && matchingFeatures[0].toLowerCase() === searchValue.toLowerCase()) {
    
    console.log('Only result: ' + matchingFeatures[0])
  }
  
//If there are several option, populate the datalist options
  else if (matchingFeatures.length > 0) {
    //Add a datalist of the matching features below the searchBox
    let datalist = document.getElementById("searchBoxResults");
    datalist.innerHTML = "";
    matchingFeatures.forEach(function (feature) {
      let option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = feature;
      datalist.appendChild(option);
    });
  } else { //If no results
    //Add a message to the datalist to inform of no results
    console.log("no results");
    let datalist = document.getElementById("searchBoxResults");
    datalist.innerHTML = "";
    let option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = "No result";
    datalist.appendChild(option);
  }
});
```

But, the "No result" text is never showing, even though the corresponding console log is displayed.

Comment: because a `<datalist>` only displays his contents relatives to characters entered as input. Prefer to use `<form>` validation messaging